# Cloud object storage

Tags: cloud, rackspace-cloud, openstack, openstack-swift, cloud-storage

I wish to offer a cloud based object storage system to my customers. For this I would need a software able to handle multi-user, multi-domain and multi-tenant and local SAN, as storing the data on S3 or other external CDN's etc. is not an option. Multi-tier storage could be an option as well. Multi protocol to access and store data like WebDAV or any other protocols used by mobile devices and operating systems.

Up to now I've found Openstack which seems usable for my use case, but Openstack only brings the raw backend (Swift) and all frontend components have to be coded and integrated, even user based access control to the containers is not available (at least not in Horizon).

Are there any other, preferably free and open source software?
Do you know of comparable solutions like Rackspace cloud?

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 1):

Putting a local SAN for storage may turn out to be expensive.  I am not sure if this is a free service or paid service but you may want to consider using commodity high-density storage (www.45drives.com).  For the software piece, in addition to what has already been mentioned, you can download the Cloudian community edition http://www.cloudian.com/ (it is free up to 100 TB but you may have to pay for support).  The final part is the applications that work with your object storage software. If your object storage is S3-compatible, there are 300+ applications that should work out of the box.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

rackspace makes use of swift.  which is the same thing openstack makes use of.

their github is here:

https://github.com/rackspace

you may find some useful additions there.

also check out ceph.

http://ceph.com/ceph-storage/file-system/

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use [ownCloud](http://owncloud.org/) and as for storage you can go ahead with [OpenStack Swift](http://docs.openstack.org/developer/swift/)

You will get most of the features you are looking for, its free and open source.